# Web service for retrieving records using php xml-rpc protocol

Tags: php, xml, web-services, xml-rpc

I am trying to implement a web service using PHP. I am following xml-rpc protocol.

I am trying to call a function through index file and display records from the database but when i try to call the function in file server2 nothing is printed on the screen just a blank white screen is showed up here is my code so far.

Kindly help me out with this I have spent hours searching about this but cannot find any help

server2.php

```
<?php
$request_xml = file_get_contents("php://input");
function say_hello($method_name, $args) {

    $dbLink = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','saad','enstructo');
    if (!$dbLink) {
    echo "ERROR";
}
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Admin";
     if ($result = mysqli_query($dbLink,$query)) {
         while($getquery = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $returnquery[] =array($result['username'],$result['email']) ;
        }
     }
    return $returnquery;
}

$xmlrpc_server = xmlrpc_server_create();
xmlrpc_server_register_method($xmlrpc_server, "say_hello", "say_hello");
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
print xmlrpc_server_call_method($xmlrpc_server, $request_xml, array());
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php 
$request = xmlrpc_encode_request("say_hello", array('10'));
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array(
    'method' => "POST",
    'header' => "Content-Type: text/xml\r\nUser-Agent: PHPRPC/1.0\r\n",
    'content' => $request
)));
$server = 'http://localhost/rpc/basic/server2.php';
$file = file_get_contents($server, false, $context);
$response = xmlrpc_decode($file);
echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: In both files? and can you tell me is the format of server2.php file is correct i mean the connection with the database and data retrieval logic is implemented correctly? or it might has to do something with the display?

Comment: I have tried it but nothing is happening again